# Integration Jira Cloud with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jira, jira-plugin, jira-agile

I want to integrate Jenkins with JIRA Cloud. 
I want Jenkins to start build job when i'm updating Issue Status in JIRA.

example: when the issue in jira is going from status IN PROGRESS to DEV COMPLETED, I want Jenkis to start a build.

regards, Maja

Answer (score 0):

Usually the flow is a little bit different.

- After you done with the development you should add JIRA ticket number in commit.
- Then create pull request (if you use Git as VCS) and merge it to main branch.
- Git server will trigger build on the Jenkins side (you should find Jenkins plugin for your case).
- After build is done there Jenkins can send update status to Jira (via Jenkins [JIRA plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JIRA+Plugin)

There are some variations. For example you want to allow merge only when build on Jenkins was successful. In this case JIRA update should be performed by Git service.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your fast response, but we got different situation than the given answer. I will try to explain clearly. 
1. we got Jira on cloud that successfully communicate with Gitlab. (there is a build in jenkins after commit in Jira)
2. and we got one test Jenkins on our local machine
Jira is configured in Jenkins and we got all needed plugins in Jenkins. 
Now we want, with every changed status on the issue in Jira (from IN PROGRESS to DEV COMPLETED), Jenkins to make an automatic build on the job.

Additionaly, Is there any Jenkins Plugin for Jira CLOUD that could help us?

Comment: How did you get step 2 to work, specifically getting your loval Jenkins to work with Jira Cloud? I'm trying to find a resource that makes sense of what to do but I'm not seeing anything.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, there is no Jenkins plugin / add-on for JIRA cloud, even though it is in high demand. It is rumored there may be one coming out in November / December 2017 as a beta.

If you are using Bitbucket, I'd recommend checking out Pipelines. Or, take a look at Bamboo or TeamCity as these tools integrate directly with JIRA Software Cloud.